# Making async calls in onBeforeMount Vue3

Tags: asynchronous, vuejs3

I'm trying to make async calls in the onBeforeMount() hook in Vue 3 but it looks like the component still mounts itself before the full execution of onBeforeMount callback.

Here is my code (everything is in `<script setup>`) :

```js
// Parent component
const allRequests: Ref<Array<ITaskData>> = ref([])

onBeforeMount(async () => {
    allRequests.value = await Task.getTasks()
})
```

After getting the results I'm sending `allRequests` to my child component, and when I print it in the template it's ok, but when I want to use it on the `onMounted` hook it's empty. If I print it with a setTimeout it's good and I see my data.
Here is a part of the code :

```js
// Child component
const data: Ref<Array<ITaskData>> = ref([])

const props = defineProps({
    tableData: {
        type: Array,
        required: true,
    },
})
onMounted(() => {
    // Here I get []
    console.log(props.tableData)

    // Here I get the array I passed as a prop in the parent
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(props.tableData)
    }, 1000)
    
})
```

Is there something I didn't understand in the Vue 3 lifecycle ?
I thought I could just make my calls in a store and then access the data from there but I think a store is a little bit too much for my app.

Comment: the lifecycle timing isn't something you can physically control in the way you're thinking. 
 the next hook doesn't wait for the previous hook to finish. the hooks are just there as opportunities for you as a developer to have some specific code _begin_ executing.

Comment: one way you can immediately react to an async operation finishing is to use a [watcher](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/watchers.html)

Comment: why you cannot fetch on the component creation with IIFE (why a hook?) why do you need your data at onMounted(). use computed() to derive from the fetch data to use in the template.

Answer (score 0):

You got it right. Vue doesn't awaits for your callback. Personally I use some boolean to conditionally render child component, and switching it only when I got all data. It is also useful to show load state in a meanwhile.

```
// Parent component
const allRequests: Ref<Array<ITaskData>> = ref([])
const initComplte = ref(false)

onBeforeMount(async () => {
    allRequests.value = await Task.getTasks()
    initComplete.value = true
})
```

And parent template will have something like

```
<template>
  <child-component v-if="initComplete" :data="allrequests" />
  <!--- optional loader  -->
  <loader v-else />
</template>
```

Comment: Thanks ! It works well and it does not requires to change the whole structure of my code. I'll use this in my app !